# java scripts : events configurable

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript :

My requirement is that I need to make events configurable ( comma separated ) like configurable interval. How will i do it.Plz suggest.

like var events_list=mousedown,mousemove,scroll

```
var interval = 7000;
    function Init () {
        if (document.addEventListener) {  
            document.addEventListener ("mousedown", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
            document.addEventListener ("mouseup", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
            document.addEventListener ("mousemove", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
            document.addEventListener ("keydown", function () { ChangeState ()}, false);
           document.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
        }
    }
    setInterval(function(){        
    myFunction();},interval);
}
```

Comment: java is to javascript like car is to carpet...

Comment: @Dahaka or ham to hamster :)

Comment: guys whats going on ??

Comment: You had java as a tag, but java and javascript are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you want is not possible:

```
var events_list = mousedown,mousemove,scroll
```

In your example mousedown, mousemove and scroll will be considered variables and will throw an error because they are not declared. You can make them configurable as a list of elements in a string separed by comma:

```
var events_list = "mousedown,mousemove,scroll";
```

Then split them into an array and loop through it:

```
function Init () {
    var events_list = "mousedown,mousemove,scroll";
    if (document.addEventListener) {  
        events_list.split(',').forEach(function (eventName) {
          document.addEventListener(eventName, function () {
              ChangeState();
          }, false);
        });
    }
}
```